# Excessive drooling for a 4 year old

Tags: mouthing

I have a 4 year old who has been excessively drooling.  It has caused some issues with a rash around his mouth, mostly after a heavy night of sleep and in the morning.  We have seen a doctor to see if there is anything wrong with him physically.  Nothing wrong with his mouth or lips, nothing swollen (like tonsils or adnoids or gums).  The doctor did say to give it some time and it could just be a growth spurt causing changes in his mouth/jaw area so its open during the night, thus causing the excessive drooling.  The recommendation to wait it out and then see if there is something that needs to be done.

Has anyone else heard of this or been through something similar?  Possibly even in relation to there being something swollen, or in relation to tonsils and adnoids and such?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Medical advice is off-topic on this site. You might be able to ask on Health.SE if you depersonalize it. You've seen a doctor; if it continues or worsens, you can always ask to be referred to a specialist. Again, welcome.

Comment: Thank you, my question wasn't regarding medical advice.  it was regarding if someone else has been through something similar and if they had any general ideas (besides medical as we are already taking the medical route).  Sorry I didn't make that part clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not related, but our kid was heavy drooler around 1-2 years old. They told us if this continued we should start doing exercises like: making your kid drink through a straw (teaches the kid to breath more through nose which then reduces drooling).

where is some more information: http://www.aboutkidshealth.ca/En/HealthAZ/ConditionsandDiseases/MouthandToothDisorders/Pages/Drooling-Excessive.aspx (just google heavy drooling toddler)

I'd suggest taking doctors advice, if it stays for a while (depending on how bad it is I would act faster) then contact a specialized child doctor, they might give you more tips and tricks on what to do next.

Comment: Thank you Joel, this is what I was looking for, for some advice if others have been through it.  I know to I should always look at the doctors for medical advice, especially if it worsens.  Thank you.